# LINQ: How to add multiple fields for grouping

Tags: c#, linq

this code apply grouping on party name whose ordinal position is 12

```
group line by line[12] into newGroup
```

now i want to know how to apply group on multiple field whose ordinal position is 0 means `line[0]`

`line[0]` will have date and time both. i just like to group on time part. this way i can extract time portion

```
DateTime.Parse(line[0].Substring(line[0].Length-8))

var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"M:\smdr(backup08-06-2015).csv");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());

var groupOfUser = from line in csvLinesData 
                  group line by line[12] into newGroup 
                  orderby newGroup.Key 
                  select newGroup;

var user = (from userOfGrp in groupOfUser
            select
                new User()
                    {
                        CSRName = userOfGrp.Key,
                        Incomming = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "I"),
                        Outgoing = userOfGrp.Count(x => x[4] == "O")
                    }).ToList();
```

1) just help me to group on multiple field one is **line[12] and other one is line[0]**
2) `line[0]` will have date and time portion like **"2015/06/08 07:59:12"** and i have to apply group on only time portion on `line[0]`

### EDIT 1

this line `group r by new { prop1 = r[12], ((DateTime)r[0]).TimeOfDay } into g` throwing error **Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'**

```
void Main()
{
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\smdr.csv");
            var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());
            var csvData = csvLinesData.Where(l => (l[6] != "VM Channel" && l[6] != "Voice Mail")).ToArray();
            var user = (from r in csvData
                        group r by new { prop1 = r[12], Time = ((DateTime)r[0]).TimeOfDay } into g
                        orderby g.Count()
                        select new User 
                        {
                            CSRName=g.Key,
                            Incomming=(from r1 in g
                                      where r1[3]=="I"
                                      select r1).Count(),
                            outgoing = (from r1 in g
                                        where r1[3] == "O"
                                        select r1).Count()

                        }).ToList();
}

class User
{
    public string CSRName;
    public int outgoing;
    public int Incomming;

}
```

Comment: @ryanyuyu: No; that's for ordering.

Comment: Unrelated: processing csv yourself is not advisable (splitting by comma, etc.). You better use a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you need this:

```
from line in csvLinesData 
group line by new 
              { 
                  prop1 = line[12],
                  Time = DateTime.Parse(line[0]).TimeOfDay
               } into newGroup 
orderby newGroup.Key.prop1, newGroup.Key.Time 
select newGroup;
```

Since `line[0]` is a string (apparently), you have to parse it to a `DateTime` value. I show the most simple method to do this, but maybe you should build in some more safety because not each string can be parsed to a `DateTime`. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Note that the anonymous type has named properties, you probably want to rename `prop1`.

Comment: can we write this `new { prop1 = line[12], ((DateTime)line[0]).TimeOfDay }` just remove time= is it ok?

Comment: please see my edit 1. i encounter error when try to run the code by linqpad.

Comment: OK, you need to parse the string. And yes, you can remove the `Time =` part.

Comment: now query run successfully but no data return. i have one request please download my csv file from this location http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=22225722172003614028 from where anyone can download. just click on test.csv file link

Comment: No no, we don't like moving targets at StackOverflow. If your original question is answered you may vote it up if you like, and mark it as accepted, if it helped you. Then, if new questions arise, you just ask a new question.

Comment: Also, referring to external sources is not encouraged. Questions work best if they are self-contained.